# Program to create a multiplication table

Tags: fortran

```
program loops

implicit none

integer x
integer::y

do x=1,10
  y=3*x
  print*,"3 times ",x,"=",y
end do

end
```

I want to create a multiplication table for 3. The program can be compiled and runs, but the formatting or the display does not look good as there is lot of spaces. How can I improve or do formatting to make the display look good?

Comment: Use your favourite references to learn about the `write` statement and about `edit descriptors` and about `format`ing in general.  Even a browse around here on SO will lead you in some useful directions.

Comment: `write(*,'(I3," times 3 = ",I5)') x,y ` may help you